# How to edit text of Please specify the product's required option(s)

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, edit

I need to translate Please specify the product's required option(s).
I issued a new 'locale' folder with a 'translate.csv' file, does not work. I tried en_US files but no luck sofar.
Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you created a file under `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/locale/en_US/translate.csv`. That is a good starting point. First try the following entries in this file (used multiple translations, because I am not quite sure which one you are after):

```
"Please specify the product required option(s)","Your custom translation here."
"Please specify the product required option(s).","Your custom translation here."
"Please specify the product\'s option(s).","Your custom translation here."
"Please specify the product\'s required option(s).","Your custom translation here."
```

If that does not work, try the following:

```
"Mage_Catalog::Please specify the product required option(s)","Your custom translation here."
"Mage_Catalog::Please specify the product required option(s).","Your custom translation here."
"Mage_Catalog::Please specify the product\'s option(s).","Your custom translation here."
"Mage_Catalog::Please specify the product\'s required option(s).","Your custom translation here."
```

Mind that there are [multiple quite similar texts](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv#L481), so make sure you edit the right one.

Comment: Thanks Simon, I did not have a en_US folder and translate.csv file there yet. Tried that + the Mage Catalog option, no success

Comment: Make sure that you replaced the `[package]` and `[theme]` placeholders above with the appropriate values. You have to place the file in the template which is actually used.

Comment: btw should it be product\'s in stead of product's? I have seen that before.

Comment: Please see my edit. If you put the file in the correct folder (in the folder of the template you are using), this should definitely work.

Comment: In translate.csv does not work. I placed it in app/design/frontend/default/mapple/locale/en_US/translate.csv. with 755 permission, 644 did not work.
Which Mage_Catalog file?

Comment: Are you sure you are using `en_US` as a language? If not, you of course have to use another folder which corresponds to your language.

Comment: Ok well I did not get that 'of course' part so now it works perfect, thanks so much Simon

Comment: Then please consider accepting this answer (tick in the left column of the answer).

Comment: I have the same issue with a line
No Payment Information Required 
at checkout. I have added that line in the translate.csv file but the translation does not show.

Comment: You could try it with various prefixes like `Mage_Payment::`, `Mage_Checkout::`, `Mage_Sales::`, `Mage_XmlConnect::`, but not sure about this one.

Comment: Ok I will, do you mean look for the sentence and then edit it?